# django last 30 entry list with count

Tags: django

With a model like this in Django, how to retrive 30 days entries with count how many were added on that day.

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    ...
    entered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Getting the last 30 days entries is easy:

```
today = datetime.date.today()
thirty_days_ago = today - datetime.timedelta(days=30)
entries = Entry.objects.filter(entered__gte=thirty_days_ago)
```

Counting how many on each day is much trickier, because you're storing timestamps, not days - if you were using a DateField you could just do a simple aggregation. Perhaps the best thing to do is iterate through and count them per day:

```
from collections import defaultdict
counts = defaultdict(int)
for entry in entries.order_by('entered'):
    date = entry.entered.date()
    days = (today - date).days
    counts[days] += 1
```

Now `counts` is a dictionary whose keys are the number of days before today, and the values are the number of entries on that day.

Comment: thanks, getting this error
"Caught an exception while rendering: zip argument #2 must support iteration" with template as: 
{% for key, value in counts %}
{{ key }}: {{ value }}
{% endfor %}"

Comment: try `{% for key, value in counts.items %}`

Comment: getting "Caught an exception while rendering: 'int' object is not iterable" 
is this is in view okay for dictionary:
    return render_to_response('page.html', {'counts': counts},
            context_instance=RequestContext(request)
            )